# WordPress Backend does not load Styles correctly

Tags: wordpress

I have an issue with a WordPress 5.8 Instance. The Page does not load the styles correctly in Backend. All pages in backend are affected with the issue.

There are no errors in Dev-Consoe, only a warning. `DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://bkijmpolkanhdehnlnabfooghjdokakc/content.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

When I set WordPress error logging = true there are no errors shown.

Here are two images with the error. Any hints for me?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Theme uses bellvue v2 Theme

added child Theme functions.php

```
<?php
// CUSTOM STYLE CSS EINBINDEN
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_style', 9999 );
function enqueue_child_theme_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dtbwp_css_child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(
        'dtbwp_style',
    ), 1.0 );
}


// Font einbinden
function tmu_custom_fonts( $standard_fonts ){
$my_custom_fonts = array();
$my_custom_fonts['Frankie'] = array(
'label' => 'Frankie',
'variants' => array('regular'),
'stack' => 'Frankie, sans-serif',
);
$my_custom_fonts['DINPro'] = array(
'label' => 'DINPro',
'variants' => array('regular'),
'stack' => 'DINPro, sans-serif',
);
$my_custom_fonts['DINPro-Bold'] = array(
'label' => 'DINPro-Bold',
'variants' => array('bold'),
'stack' => 'DINPro-Bold, sans-serif',
);
return array_merge_recursive( $my_custom_fonts, $standard_fonts );
}
add_filter( 'kirki/fonts/standard_fonts', 'tmu_custom_fonts', 20 );
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which action hook did you use to enqueue your styles? `admin_enqueue_scripts`?

Comment: added some infos above @Ruvee

Answer (score 0):

Solution was:

Wordpress did not show that there was an update for the theme. Manually checking the versions on Theme-Forest + manually uploading the new version solved the problem.